# Centering Floating Action Button in navigation bar Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I have created a navigation bar in flutter, now I want to add a button in between the navbar icons as shown in this image.
[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvX6X.png)

But I am getting this. [I am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qob8E.jpg)

I brought the button in the middle with following code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Icon(PhosphorIcons.plusLight,color: navBarColor),
),
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

Is there any way to bring it in the middle of the navbar?

If there is a there is a way to give circle background color to a navbar destination, then it would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an alignment to the fab

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
              
              child:  FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
               
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
floatingActionButton: Stack( [ Position( bottom: -20, FloatingActionButton( onPressed: () {}, child: const Icon(PhosphorIcons.plusLight,color: navBarColor), ) ) ]), floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a FloatingActionButton with a navbar like that. Just add the + action as another button in the middle of the navbar.